# Riemann Surface, existence of meromorphic function.

Tags: riemann-surfaces, complex-geometry

There is a question which has been perplexing me. Given $S$ a compact Riemann surface, $p$ and $q$ two distinct points. Is it always possible to find a meromorphic function on $S$ which is zero on $p$ but not on $q$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose the genus of $S$ is $g$ then consider the divisor $m\cdot p - q$. By Riemann-Roch theorem, we have 
$$ l(m\cdot p - q) - l(K - m\cdot p +q) = m - g $$
where $K$ is a canonical divisor. Let $m$ be large enough such that $deg(K - m\cdot p + q) = 2g - 1 - m < 0$ i.e. $l(K - m\cdot p + q) = 0$, then the dimension of $L(m\cdot p - q)$ grows linearly. Thus, there exists a meoromorphic function $f \in L((m+1)\cdot p - q)$ but $f \notin L(m\cdot p - q)$. That is, there exists a function $f$ that has a pole of order $m+1$ at $p$ and a zero at $q$ as you want.

Comment: Of course, to prove that the R-R theorem applies to compact connected Riemann surfaces, one needs to prove _existence_ of some suitable sort of functions... which essentially reduces to "Dirichlet's principle" about achieving the minimum of a functional. But this is false as originally formulated! :)  But/and a true version was proven c. 1906 by G. Levi and 1907 by G. Frobenius. Whew! :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Wow, thanks for telling this interesting background!

Comment: I believe there are two minor typos in your usage of the Riemann-Roch theorem. If I understand correctly, the divisor in the second term should have a `q` where there is a `1` and the degree of the divisor should be `m-1`.

Comment: @Wyvellum Yes indeed, thanks for your noting!

Answer (score 1):

The magic words are [the Riemann-Roch Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem)

Comment: Sorry, I am quite lost. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: A collection of points with integer weights on a Riemann surface is a _divisor_. THe RR theorem tells you the dimension of the space of meromorphic functions which have the prescribed (by the weights) orders of zeros and poles at the given points.