# Algebraic dependence of meromorphic functions on a compact Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I am trying to show given two meromorphic functions $f,g$ on a compact Riemann surface $X$ that there exists a non-zero polynomial $P \in \mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ such that $P(f,g) = 0$.

I have seen this question [Meromorphic Function in a Compact Riemann Surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072972/meromorphic-function-in-a-compact-riemann-surface) however I didn't find the discussion very useful.

Firstly, why should I expect such a result to be true?

Also, how can I go about proving this?

One thing I noticed is a polynomial in $f,g$ can be written as $(1,f,...,f^r)A(1,g,...,g^r)^t$ for some matrix of coefficients $A$, but I did not find a way to use this.

Comment: If you cannot solve this, take a look for instance at the end of chapter 7 of R.Narasimhan "Compact Riemann surfaces".